# How to inform in Android Studio, to one class of IDE, to pass from a screen to another screen, sliding the finger on the screen of the cell phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I created two simple classes in Android Studio: MainActivity and Activity2.
I created a code in which, when the smartphone is on the MainActivity screen, a user can slide his own finger, that goes from the MainActivity screen to the Activity2 screen.
But how do you tell Android that when a user slides their finger on the screen, the code must pass from the MainActivity screen to the Activity2 screen?

Please, can anyone help me?

The simple codes I wrote:

MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.r0adkll.slidr.Slidr;
import com.r0adkll.slidr.model.SlidrConfig;
import com.r0adkll.slidr.model.SlidrInterface;
import com.r0adkll.slidr.model.SlidrPosition;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SlidrConfig config = new SlidrConfig.Builder().position(SlidrPosition.RIGHT).build();
        Slidr.attach(this, config);

    }
}
```

Activity2:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.r0adkll.slidr.Slidr;
import com.r0adkll.slidr.model.SlidrInterface;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Slidr` library you are using closes/dismisses the activity by sliding it off.
We usually implement such action in the situation for example, we have `ListActivity` which displays list of item and `DetailsActivity` which displays detail of an item. If you click on the list item in `ListActivity`, we will see it's detail in `DetailsActivity`. Now, from `DetailsActivity`, we can slide it off to get back to the `ListActivity`.

So, there must be one activity in the stack to come back to. I am assuming here, the `MainActivity` is your parent activity and you are going from `MainActivity` to `Activity2`.
in that case you are trying to dismiss the `MainActivity` to go to `Activity2`. But, as far as I know, you won't be able to dismiss the host activity with this library. Instead you rather can swipe off `Activity2` to get back to `MainActivity`.

If you want to slide off `Activity2` to get back to `MainActivity`, you can follow along.

Make new style tag in your `themes.xml/styles.xml` file and add new style for `Activity2`.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Actiivty2Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

You can give any name instead of `Actiivty2Theme` but make sure `AppTheme` should be same as your apps main theme/style name. And also do not forget to assign this style for `Activity2` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Add this line to your root layout of `Activity2`.

```
android:background="@color/background_material_light"
```

Then finally, your sliding code in `onCreate()` of `Activity2`

```
SlidrConfig config = new SlidrConfig.Builder().position(SlidrPosition.RIGHT).build();
Slidr.attach(this, config);
```

You should now be able to slide off `Activity2` to get back to `MainActivity`.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much, Skafle.

Comment: If my answer resolves your problem then please mark it as accepted answer so that it would be helpful for other with the same question.